# Deriative of ${\frac{(\ln x)^{2}}{\sqrt{x}}}$ is not correct

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Using the chain and quotient rules,  I get: $${\frac{2*\ln x}{x*\sqrt{x}}-\frac{(\ln x)^{2}}{2*\sqrt{x}}}$$

**Answer:$(0,0)$ - min, $(1,0)$-  min, $(e^4$,$\frac{16}{e^2})$ - max**

Can anyone please describe how I should continue, because I don't know if I should (clearly yes because of the answers) include $0$ in the set of solutions, and by meaning of domain, in the original function x can't be negative...

Comment: The first term in the numerator should be $$\sqrt x \, 2(\ln x) \frac 1x = \frac{2 \ln x}{\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: yes I just noticed. I changed it

Answer (score 1):

I got the following: 
$$u={\frac{(\ln x)^{2}}{\sqrt{x}}}$$
$$u'={\frac{2\ln x}{x\sqrt{x}}}-{(\ln x)^{2}}\frac 12x^{-3/2}$$
$$u'={\frac{2\ln x}{x\sqrt{x}}}-\frac {{(\ln x)^{2}}} {2x\sqrt x}$$
$$u'={\frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{x}}}\left (2-\frac 12\ln x \right )$$

Comment: ok, I see where I am mistaken

Comment: I get x=1 and x=e^4. should I also include x=0(because denominator of f ' (x) is x)?

Comment: Why would you include an $x$ that makes the denominator $0$????  The denominator being $0$ makes the entire thing undefined.  That is *not* a solution.  That is about as opposite of a solution as you can get!

Comment: @fleablood Please, ping the commenter or they won't see your comment.

Comment: @fleablood but if I put x=0 in deriative table and check for x>0 and for x<0 I can get minima just like in the answers. I am sorry to irritate you, it's just doesn't seem so trivial for me. because sometimes altough the derative function can't be defined in a certain  x doesN't mean that the function it self undefined there also. and when you say "... makes the entire thing undefined" do you mean the function or deriative? sir please, be more accurate, because speaking in these terms indicates that maybe you dont understand entirely the concept....

Comment: @user6394019 In this case I mean both.  Sure the derivative may be defined in places where the function isn't but if you need to solve $\frac {gooby}x = 0$ why would you think you need to include $x = 0$?  If $x = 0$ then $\frac {gooby}0 \ne 0$ so it is not a solution.  In fact $\frac {gooby} 0$ is not even defined.

Comment: "should I also include x=0(because denominator of f ' (x) is x)?".  Because the denominator of $f'(x)$ is $x$ is precisely why you should *NOT* include $x = 0$.  If a value makes the denominator $0$ than you must *AVOID* that value.  You absolutely should *NOT* include it.

Answer (score 1):

With a function like this it can be convenient to use the (formal) logarithmic derivative: if
$$
f(x)=\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
then
$$
\ln f(x)=\ln\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}=
\ln((\ln x)^2)-\ln(\sqrt{x})=2\ln\ln x-\frac{1}{2}\ln x
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2\frac{1}{\ln x}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x}=
\frac{4-\ln x}{2x\ln x}
$$
and finally
$$
f'(x)=\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{4-\ln x}{2x\ln x}=\frac{(4-\ln x)\ln x}{2x\sqrt{x}}
$$

Your function is only defined for $x>0$. The derivative vanishes where $4-\ln x=0$ or $\ln x=0$, that is, at $x=1$ or $x=e^4$.

---

Some care should be used with this method, but in essence it works without the need of checking for the existence of the single steps. Only the final result is what we should care about.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we get by the Quotient rule

$$\frac{2\ln(x)\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x}-(\ln(x))^2\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well $[(\ln x)^2]' = 2(\ln x)\frac 1x$ by chain rule.

And $[\sqrt{x}]' = \frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt x}$

so $[\frac {[(\ln x)^2]}{\sqrt{x}}]' =$

$\frac {[(\ln x)^2]'\sqrt{x} - [(\ln x)^2][\sqrt{x}]'}{[\sqrt{x}]^2}=$ (by quotient rule)

$\frac { 2(\ln x)\frac 1x\sqrt{x} - (\ln x)^2 \frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt x}}{x}$

which can be simplified to

$\frac {\ln x(2-\frac {\ln x}2)}{x\sqrt{x}}$

That equals $0$ if $x = 1$.  Or if $\ln x = 4$ or $x= e^4$.

So $\frac {\ln^2 1}{\sqrt 1} = 0$ for $x=0$ so $(1,0)$ is an extrema.

And $\frac {\ln^2 e^4}{\sqrt{e^4}} = \frac {16}{e^2}$ for $x = e^4$ so $(e^4,\frac {16}{e^2})$ is another extrema.

I have absolutely no idea why you got your derivative over a numerater of $1$ nor do I have any idea why you thought $x = 0$ could be a solution to $\frac{\frac{2*\ln x}{x*\sqrt{x}}-\frac{(\ln x)^{2}}{2*\sqrt{x}}}{1} = 0$.  It's clearly undefined for $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^u$ therefore $$f(x)=u^2e^\dfrac{-u}{2}$$and we have $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=(2ue^\dfrac{-u}{2}-\dfrac{u^2}{2}e^\dfrac{-u}{2})\dfrac{1}{x}$$by resubstituting $$f'(x)=\left(2\ln x-\dfrac{\ln^2x}{2}\right)\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt x}$$